# How to transpile typescript to javascript on Docker volume?

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose

I have a Typescript node application.  The main file is `server.ts`.  I want to run this application in a Docker container.  I have a build step in my `Dockerfile` that runs the Typescript transpilation, example:

```
FROM node:9.9 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY ... # copy the source files to the docker container 

RUN npm install && \
npm run build  # <-- runs Typescript transpile

FROM node:9.9

COPY --from=build /path/to/source/files /app

WORKDIR /path/to/server.js directory

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I use `docker-compose` to configure the container for development

```
my-app:
  build:
    context: /path/to/build/context
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  command: bash -c "npm install -g nodemon && nodemon server.js"
  network_mode: "host"
  volumes:
    - /path/to/server.js/directory/local:/path/to/server.js/directory/in/container
```

Since the Typescript is transpiled during the image build phase, the `server.js` file is created within the container.  So if I run `docker-compose` without the volumes included, the `server.js` file is there and the container starts fine.  If I run `docker-compose` with the volumes, the `server.js` file is not there, just `server.ts`.  I *think* this is because locally, I don't have `server.js` since it is built during the image build phase, and since the volume is referencing that directory, it is not there in the container.  Is there any way that I could build the container and have the transpiled `js` files from the build phase in that volume?

Answer (score 1):

An idea would be to copy your transpiled files into a different folder during the building of the image and link them to the `/path/to/server.js/directory/in/container` directory before you start `node`. The `command` in docker-compose would be something like:

```
command: bash -c "ln -s /path/to/built/files /path/to/server.js/directory/in/container; npm install ..."
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are trying to support two different scenarios:

- use a pre-built/transpiled version of your code (default scenario)
- if a volume is specified, use/hot-transpile code from a mounted volume (development scenario)

I don't have experience with your exact situation, but in situations where I wanted to support different runtime scenarios, I would put that logic in a bash script, and set that script as the entrypoint.

e.g.

```
# ...
COPY run-script run-script

# ...

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "run-script"]
```

And your `run-script` could do something like check if a specific pre-determined directory/path exists, and perform a different action than the default of just running your bundled script.